# Why doesn't this fortran code work?

Tags: fortran, prims-algorithm

Hey, I wrote this (fortran) with the aim of finding the minimum spanning tree of a bunch of points (*syscount* of them). I know for a fact that this approach works, since i wrote it in javascript earlier today. js is slow though, and i wanted to see how much faster fortran would be!!
only problem is it's not working, i'm getting an annoying error;

> prims.f95:72.43:
>
> if((check == 1) .and. (path(nodesin(j))(k) < minpath)) then
>
> ```
>                                  1
> ```
>
> Error: Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1)

What the hell is that about?! the 43rd character on the line is the "h" of "path"

```
nodesin(1) = 1

do i = 1,syscount-1
    pathstart = -1
    pathend = -1
    minpath = 2000

    do j = 1,i
        do k = 1, syscount

            check = 1
            do l = 1, i
                if(nodesin(l) == k) then
                    check = 0
                end if
            end do

            if((check == 1) .and. (path(nodesin(j))(k) < minpath)) then
                minpath = path(nodesin(j))(k)
                pathstart = nodesin(j)
                pathend = k
            end if

        end do
    end do

    nodesin(i+1) = pathend
    minpaths(i)(1) = pathstart
    minpaths(i)(2) = pathend

end do
```

Also, i'm fairly new to fortran, so i have a few other questions;

can i use && instead of .and. ?

is there a versions of the for(object in list){} loop found in many other languages?

is there a verion of the php function in_array ? i.e. bool in_array(needle,haystack), and if there is, is there a better way of doing it than:

```
check = false
Asize = size(array)
do i = 1, Asize
    if(array(i) == needle) then
        check = true
    end if
end do
```

then to using the check variable to see if it's there?

(I haven't posted anything on stackoverflow before. please don't get angry if i've broken loads of etiquette things!)

Comment: Can you use == in Fortran?  Last time I used it (Fortran 77 - I know the world has changed since then) you used .EQ. and .LT. and so on.  I know Fortran 90 did a lot of modernizing, but I don't know what it changed.  Try using .EQ., .LT., .LE., .NE., .GT., .GE. as well as .AND., .OR., and .NOT. and see whether that helps.  Classic Fortran speak - but likely to work.

Comment: this site: http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap03/logical.html

says == should work,

also, it works a few lines higher, and if i change it it just shifts the error along to 72.46.

doesn't look like that's the problem :-(

Comment: Are your sure about that expression "path(nodesin(j))(k)"? What is "path" and "nodesin"? How they are defined in code?

Comment: If "path" is two-dimensional array to access it's elements one should use "path(i, j)" syntax and not "path(i)(j)".

Comment: Is 'check' a BOOLEAN?  If so, do you need to use .FALSE. or .TRUE. or their modern counterparts - or are you allowed to use 1?  Since the message complains about '1'... still fishing in the dark.  Though your needle and haystack code suggests check is a BOOLEAN and that 'false' and 'true' might work where 1 does not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have defined `path` and `minpaths` as two-dimensional arrays. Multi-dimensional arrays are accessed differently in Fortran when compared to C-like languages. In Fortran you separate the indices by commas within one set of parentheses.

I'm guessing by the use of these variables they are integer arrays. Here is how you access elements of those arrays (since you didn't share your variable declarations I am making up the shape of these arrays):

```
integer :: path(n1, n2)
integer :: minpaths(n3, 2)
```

your if statement should be:

```
if((check == 1) .and. (path(nodesin(j), k) < minpath)) then
```

your access to minpaths should be:

```
minpaths(i, 1) = pathstart
minpaths(i, 2) = pathend
```

Also, if you are not using `IMPLICIT NONE` I recommend you consider it. Not using it is dangerous, and you are using variable names that are close to each other (`minpath` and `minpaths`). You could save hours of hair pulling debugging by using `IMPLICIT NONE`.

Answer (score 1):

While .EQ. can be replaced with ==, there is still only .AND.

For your code block to check whether a "variable is there", you can use "where" and have much shorter code!

In Fortran >= 90 statements and functions can operate on arrays so that explicit loops don't have to be used as frequently.

There is no for (object in list), but using the where statement can do something very similar.

Many of the intrinsic functions that act on arrays also take masks as optional arguments to selectively operate.

I suggest reading a book to learn about these features.  I like the one by Metcalf, Reid and Cohen.  In the meantime, the second Wikipedia article may help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran_95_language_features